# Android Login Prombems (should use AsyncTask)

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask, network-programming

I am developing a part of my app, and need some Help. My app send some data (username,pass) to the server, and the login is success, then make a Toast("success!"). Im already made the php file, what is good workin, and a mySQL database. My problem is, when Im testing from the Emulator, my app is frozen. I know why, because I want to start network communication from the UI. AsyncTast is going to be a good option to solve my problem, but I dont know how to use it.

There is the code:

**Php:**

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="mobiledb"; // Database name
$tbl_name="androidlogin"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['username'];
$mypassword=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$myusername' and pass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){


    echo "true";

}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";

}
?>
```

**Java/Android:**

```
package rs.sqllogin.androidloginsql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etUser, etPass;
    Button btnLogin;

    String username, password;
    // creat httpclient as the form container
    HttpClient httpclient;
    // httpPost method
    HttpPost httppost;
    // create an array list for the input data to be sent
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    // create a httpResponse and HttpEntity
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpEntity entity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialise();

    }

    private void initialise() {
        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create a new deafult httpclient
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Create a new HTTP Post with URL
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/checklogin.php");

        try {
            username = etUser.getText().toString();
            password = etPass.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = converStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();



            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {

             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else

            {

             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "False", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private static String converStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing Network related work on main thread, which is not allowed.

Comment: I'm curious, how can I do it right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class GetAuthentication extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    ProgressDialog pd ;

    private Context _context;



    public GetAuthentication(Context context) {
        _context = context;
    }



    protected void onPreExecute ()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(_context);
        pd.setTitle("Processing");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Create a new HTTP Post with URL
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/checklogin.php");

    try {

        username = params[0];            // getting the username and password passed to asynctask from button click
        password = params[1];


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        return response.getEntity().getContent().toString();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error";
        }
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String str)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(str);    //str has the String passed from doInBackground method.

            if (pd.isShowing())
                pd.dismiss();
        String myStr = converStreamToString(str);



        if(myStr.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {

         Toast.makeText(_context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }else

        {

         Toast.makeText(_context, "False", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }

  }   // end of AsyncTask

}   // end of Activity
```

Change your onClick by the following

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create a new deafult httpclient
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // Create a new HTTP Post with URL
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8080/checklogin.php");

        try {
            String user = etUser.getText().toString();
            String pwd = etPass.getText().toString();

            new GetAuthentication(MainActivity.this).execute(user, pwd);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


            }
    } // end of onClick
```

Comment: Im used your code, and I got the following errors: 1. doInBackground need to have a return value, I see that you already made it. 2. I get an error when you want to use, the converStreamToString function. (I know these are newbie questions, but I'm a beginner, and need this to the school.) Ty for Helping.

Comment: Edited the code for return value in doInBackground (just added return error in catch block). What error do you get while calling convertStream method? Try replacing `private static String converStreamToString(InputStream is)` by `public static String converStreamToString(InputStream is)`. Change the private to public.